# Як перекласти з російської "биение торца шпинделя"?

Tags: переклад

Як перекласти з російської "биение торца шпинделя"? 
Якщо "биття шпинделю" - не дуже звучить. Це відхилення розміру деталі, яка обертається, англійською spindle run-out. 
Технічне слово, є англійський та
російський варіант, українського аналогу не можу знайти.
[image]

Comment: Дякую дуже, що відредагували питання. Останнє, що залишилося зробити, - пояснити своїми словами, що таке "биение торца шпинделя" - і ваше питання повністю відповідатиме критеріям.

Comment: @P.Vowk, та шановний Андрій наче вже пояснив — відхилення розміру деталі, яка обертається. Не зовсім очевидно, правда, до чого тут биття, але, мабуть, неточний розмір деталі й спричиняє таку поведінку деталі в процесі використання. (R2U серед варіантія для слова _[биение](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=биение&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)_ подає _калатання_, але не знаю, наскільки воно тут підходить.) Тепер соромно, що людина покращила відповідь, але відповісти ми (принаймні я) усе одно не можемо. (У принципі, R2U дає варіанти перекладів і для _шпиндель_, _торец_, але які з них підходять — хтозна.)

Comment: @Sasha [Анґлською](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=runout&highlight=on) — _вибіг_. [Пошук Ґуґла](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=вибіг+шпинделя) надає: а) _У нього вбудована функція гальмування вибігу («гальмівний резистор»)_; б) _Гальмо вибігу – миттєва зупинка обертання патрона при відпусканні_ — але не знаю чи то воно.

Comment: @stegetsj так ми маємо відштовхуватись саме від англійського варіанту, бо користувач хоче *відхилення*. І тут це *вибіг*.

Comment: а в російській мові є слово "шпиндель"?

Comment: @Sasha на стеку багато користувачів, відповідати маємо необов'язково саме ми. А ось завдяки покращенню питання ми маємо 4 голоси за й лише один голос за закриття.

Comment: @khex давайте собі раду перевірити самостійно, будь ласка: https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype=

Comment: @Sasha Вибіг - не підходить, це час обертання. Є ще формулювання англійською  "Total indicator reading" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_indicator_reading . Гадаю, що точного аналога російському і англійському варіантам немає, найбільше підходить варіант "максимальне відхилення"

Comment: От тепер я, до речі, зрозумів, що малося на увазі.

Comment: А чому Ви «вибіг» асоціюєте саме з часом?

Comment: Я також не розумію чому ви *вибіг* асціюєте з часом. Для мене воно природньо звучить як міра того наскільки свердло вибігло зі свого стандартного положення.

Comment: На фейсбук-дзеркалі цієї сторінки користувачі питають: «А що не так з биттям?»

Answer (score 1):

[«Загальний народний англійсько-український словник» на E2U](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=run-out&dicts=1) для *run-out* пропонує зокрема:

> run-out, runout [ˈrʌnaʊt] n
>
> …
>   3) *тех.* радіальне биття, вибігання; вибіг, ексцентричність *(обертового механізму)*
>   …

Але це «народний» словник, складаний добровольцями, а не обов'язково спеціалістами.

[«Великий англо-український словник» 2011 (Є. І. Гороть, Л. М. Коцюк, Л. К. Малімон, А. Б. Павлюк)](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=run-out&dicts=17) пропонує:

> 4. *тех.* ексцентричність *(обертової деталі)*;

З Вікіпедії: «[Ексцентрик](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA) — диск або інша деталь, вісь обертання якого не збігається з його геометричною віссю». Імовірно, ексцентричність — це міра того, наскільки не збігається (хоча в житті такого терміна не зустрічав). Тобто я пропоную **ексцентричність шпиндля**.

*Update: Я подумав, і тепер мені здається, що ексцентричність — не зовсім те (точніше, зовсім не те, лише один аспект). Наскільки я розумію, обертова деталь може бути ідеально відцентрованою, але все одно мати радіальне биття через те, що її поперечний переріз — не круг, а щось інше (хай навіть воно ідеально симетричне радіально). Поки що єдине, що спадає мені на думку — це **радіальне биття**.*

*Отже наразі я схиляюся до **(радіальне) биття шпиндля**. Можливо, слід додати якесь слово, типу «(радіальне) биття поверхні/торця/торчака/перечного_перерізу/тощо шпиндля». Хоча це можуть бути й не найкращі варіанти.*

Comment: було б добре доповнити своїм варіантом перекладу.

Comment: @P.Vowk, «калатання»? Тепер уже я думаю, що він не доречний.

Comment: ні, перекладу цілої фрази, а не частини.

Comment: @Sasha я пов'язую ВИБІГ з часом, тому що в цитаті указано "гальмування вибігу",  Гальмо вибігу – миттєва зупинка обертання патрона при відпусканні - тобто вмикаю гальмо - вибіг зменшується. З ексцентричністю це не пов'язано - "биття" може виникати, навіть якщо деталь ідеально циліндрична, але закріплена  (наприклад в шпинделі) із зміщенням, або під кутом, і це "биття" покаже індикатор, коли цей циліндр обертати. Фраза  (радіальне) биття шпинделя - використовується широко в технічній російській мові, але я не впевнений, що ії правильно використовувати в українській.

Comment: "калатання" - більше пов'язано з поганим (несильним) кріпленням уявного циліндру, ніж з тим, що мається на увазі.

Comment: @AndriiTereshchenko, дякую за пояснення. Нічого окрім «(радіальне) биття шпинделя» (до речі, цікаво, що деякі словники дають форму родового відмінка «шпинделя», а деякі — «шпиндля») я наразі запропонувати не можу. У технічній українських літературі словосполучення «радіальне биття» [загалом використовується](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22радіальне+биття%22).

Comment: Є ще споріднене поняття "ексцентриситет". Але поки це вимовиш, шпіндель зламається.